# subtract the given age into the current date

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two fields where one field is used to give input of user age and another field to display the date of birth as per current date.

My html code is:-

```
<div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
    <label><?php echo _('DOB'); ?> : </label>
    <input value="" type="text" name="jbs_dob" id="jbs_dob" size="17" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
    <label><?php echo _('Age'); ?> : </label>
    <input value="" class="validate[required] form-control" type="text" name="jbs_age" id="jbs_fname" size="17" />
</div>
```

My js and jquery code is:

```
$(function () {
    $("#jbs_age").click(function () {
        var jbs_dob = new Date();
        var jbs_age =$('jbs_age').val();
        var diff= jbs_dob-jbs_age;
        $( "#jbs_dob" ).html(diff);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: My exact result was while give the age display the date of birth

Comment: But what is age??? Just an integer or what? How can you retrive a date of birth just knowing the age of a person???

Comment: Age was like integer number and date of birth are current date

Comment: So lets say i'm 99yo, we are monday 1st january 2015, what is my date of birth???  Your question as asked doesn't make any sense or i still don't understand it

Comment: yes exactly while I give the user age form the form displayed his date of birth by subtracting with current date. For example if I will type the age 16 then displayed in the date of birth field like 2000-02-11

Comment: Can someone else explains me how can we know a date of birth of a person knowing only his age??? I'm feel stupid now...

Comment: @A.Wolff your last comment ha ha ha. sorry to pawan but didn't stop it.

Comment: Ok you want to substract years from current date...

Comment: You can't. It's impossible unless you know the date they were born.
You can do it the other way around, maybe that's what OP means?
If you have a DOB you can calculate the age.

Comment: @PawanDongol may be something like `new Date().getFullYear() - jbs_age`. But it will give you the year of his birth not DOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. This will return you Year of the birth. If you provide age 25 then it will show 1991 in birth day field.

```
$(function () {
        $("#jbs_age").click(function () {
          var jbs_dob = new Date();      
          var jbs_age =$('#jbs_age').val();
          var age = (jbs_dob.getFullYear() - jbs_age);
        $( "#jbs_dob" ).val(age);
      });
});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer PHPExpert  but it does not work.

Comment: Yes, so I already have mention that it will return only birth year.